# Good description and tutorial regarding System.Data.Odbc / OdbcDataReader

Tags: vb.net

Any links to good descriptions and/or tutorials (with VB.net 2008) on OdbcDataReader ?
I tried, but didn't find many. MSDN is not such a good help in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right. It's hard to find tutorials for ODBC in VB.Net. Below are the links to the ones that I found. Hope it helps.

- [Using ODBC within a .NET application](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5793285.html) - examples in VB.Net and C#
- [ODBC Database To Grid in VB.NET](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic90770.htm)